# A question about 依り代

Tags: culture

I was reading a few articles about 依り代 and there's one thing I'm wondering about. Most of what I read say that 'yorishiro' are objects or sometimes people that attract kami. The following is just my assumption because I did not find something that would specify, but, I wondered if the objects or 'vessels' (this is how I would translate in a particular context) need to have certain qualities/certain aspects in order for the kami to posses it?
I'm asking this because it might help me with something I came across for which I have formed a theory.
Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the plot, I guess.

Comment: @broccoliforest
I don't want to make wrong assumptions, so I was hoping that if someone here has more knowledge upon the subject of 依り代 to enlighten me, it would be great. After reading on a few sites and fragments in books, I wonder if kami have preferences. I read that swords for example are among the usual yorishiro, so, are swords appealing to kami that are regarded as deities of war for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, 依り代 is broadly used in any context related to spirit possession, and it can be anything or anyone. It's also commonly used outside the contexts of Japanese *shinto*. It can be a piece of paper, a sword, a tree, a rock, a doll, an animal or a human being. I think it's perfectly fine to use 依り代 to describe some ritual item used by a Voodoo priestess, for example.

According to sources, the word 依り代 was invented in the early 20th century by an ethnologist [Shinobu Orikuchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinobu_Orikuchi) to explain a certain aspect of religious belief of Japanese people. It's not a traditional *shinto* term, and by its nature, the word will not determine what a concrete 依り代 must look like.

Comment: thank you! I needed more info in order to explain something from a story.